# How to kill a process by it's port inside gulp task?

Tags: javascript, gulp

Let's say I want to kill the process on port `35729` inside my gulp task. How can I make this?

Answer (score 0):

A clean option is to use Node's `process` which has a `kill(YOUR_PID)`.

In your case, try:

```
gulp.task('KillPort', function(){
    process.kill(35729);
});
```

Another less desirable option is to use `ShellJS` to run a UNIX `exec()` call. This then allows you to run a `kill -9 PID_1 PID_2 PID_N`.

Comment: process.kill(35729) wont kill software listening on port 35729